# click a button multiple times to run the same function, java android studio

Tags: java, android, string, button, printing

when i click a button i want to print a random string, but so far i can only click it once then i have to restart to print a new one. what do i have to do to continuously print strings.

java code:

```
    public String converse = randomStarter();

public static String randomStarter() {

    Random generator = new Random();
    int rand = generator.nextInt(6);
    String starter = new String("");

    switch (rand) {

        case 0: starter = "What was your favorite subject in \n school as a kid? \n Worst?";

            break;

        case 1: starter = "My favorite room in the house is...";

            break;

        case 2: starter = "If you had 1 million dollars, what would you do with it?";

            break;

        case 3: starter = "Did you ever have a nickname? \n If so, what was it?";

            break;

        case 4: starter = "If I had magical powers I would...";

            break;

        case 5: starter = "If you were invisible for a day, \nwhat would you do?";
            break;

        case 6: starter = "5 people I would NOT like to meet...";

            break;

    }

        return starter;

}


public void printStarter(View view) {
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content)).setText(converse);

}
```

xml code to where the text is printed:

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:textColor="#2f4b66"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/dummy_content" />
```

button xml:

```
 <Button android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
            style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dummy_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="printStarter"
            />
```

Comment: Where is your JButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the same string because your variable `converse` always has the same string, when you click the button it doesn't change

```
public String converse = randomStarter();
```

The easy way out would be modifying the code for you button like this:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content)).setText(randomStarter());
```

This will work, but your code is very inefficient. The best way to do it is create an array of strings where you keep all the values, and each time the button is pressed you generate a random number and pull the string from the array whose index corresponds to that number.